# Presto check if NULL and return default (NVL analog)

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Is there any analog of NVL in Presto DB?

I need to check if a field is NULL and return a default value.

I solve this somehow like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN my_field is null THEN 0 
    ELSE my_field 
  END
FROM my_table
```

But I'm curious if there is something that could simplify this code.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The ISO SQL function for that is `COALESCE`

```
coalesce(my_field,0)
```

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html

P.S. `COALESCE` can be used with multiple arguments. It will return the first (from the left) non-NULL argument, or NULL if not found.

e.g.

```
coalesce (my_field_1,my_field_2,my_field_3,my_field_4,my_field_5)
```

Comment: Same for AWS Athena in case looking for.