# Presto MD5 Hash for multiple Columns in DB Table

Tags: sql, hash, md5, presto, amazon-athena

I am facing a challenge that's driving me crazy after two hours of trial and error...

I need to hash at least two columns of a relational table with presto (actually with Amazon Athena which uses the presto engine).

My current state is this:

```
SELECT concat(lower(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(trim(column1))))),
              lower(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(trim(column2)))))) AS HK
FROM table
limit 10
```

The issue with this is, it hashes the columns first and afterwards concatenates them what ends up looking like this, because it concatenates the hashes:

```
8f9bfe9d1345237cb3b2b205864da075ce8ae9da5b7cd6c3df2929543a9af92d
```

Instead of concatenating the strings first and then hashing it what should end up like this:

```
8f9bfe9d1345237cb3b2b205864da075
```

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on how to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**

I got a solution, but only without using the trim() function, with it the query does not work and results in an error message

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: There must be two or more concatenation arguments

Current query:

```
SELECT lower(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(concat(user, email))))) AS UserMailHK FROM table limit 10
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The input data comes a CSV file stored on AWS S3. I just created a table in Athena and am running the query on that table.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT lower(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(concat(trim(user), trim(email)))))) AS UserMailHK FROM table` ?

Comment: That works. I tried that before but I didn't have an output, it was just blank. But thanks for your answer, it's the solution!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got a solution thanks to Piotr!

```
SELECT lower(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(concat(trim(user), trim(email)))))) AS UserMailHK FROM table limit 10
```

Comment: The above won't give you any hash value if either of `user` or `email` is null. You can use the `coalesce` function to replace the null value with an empty string (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275417/12242023).