# How to fill null values with 0 in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, null, nan

In Athena, what is the most efficient way to fill null values with 0?

I think I can use `Case` statement, but I am also curious if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: There is [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275417/14843902) thread related to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`, [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html) is Presto documentation on conditions which is what Athena is built on.

```
select coalesce(myColumn, 0) from my_table_name
```